# How to instantiate a AdnroidViewModel in Linear Layout

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, android-room, viewmodel, android-viewmodel

I am creating a Custom Linear Layout view to represent a custom calender. Ealier I used SQlitehelper to get the data. But now I am migrating to Room DB.  But I couldn't instantiate AndroidViewModel and get data.

This is the AndroidViewModel

```
class AdminExpensesVM(application: Application):AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val repository:AdminExpensesRepo
     val readAll :LiveData<List<AdminExpensesData>>

    init {
        val adminExpensesDB=AdminExpensesDatabase.getInstance(application).adminExpensesDao
        repository= AdminExpensesRepo(adminExpensesDB)
        readAll=repository.getAllExpenses()
    }
   }
```

This is the Custom LinearLayout

```
class Admin_Calender : LinearLayout {

    private lateinit var adminExpensesVM: AdminExpensesVM;


constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {

  val inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
  val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.admin_calender, this)

 
  adminExpensesVM=ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(context as Application).create(AdminExpensesVM::class.java)

    }

}
```

But this cannot be done becasue it get a error casting context to application. How can I do this? Is there anyway to get application to instantiate AndroidViewModel or is there any way to do it with only context?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get your question but maybe this can help try to make it scoped with your activity

```
val adminExpensesVM: AdminExpensesVM by activityViewModels()
```

Comment: I got uresolved reference to the activityViewModel() , is there any dependancy for that?

Comment: implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.1.0'